# Python - Shallow Copy

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy

```
my_list = [15, 6, 7, 8, 35, 12, 14, 4, 10, 15]
my_new_list = my_list
my_new_list.sort()
print(my_list)
print(my_new_list)
```

```
The output:

[4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 35]
[4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 35]
```

In this piece of code, why is **my_new_list** being a *shallow copy* of **my_list**? I don't understand why it isn't a *deep copy*. And if I wanted to have a *deep copy* of **my_list** how would I do it?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: [The canonical answer to your question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns). Invest 25 minutes.

Comment: It isn't any sort of copy, of any depth.  It's *the same list*.